# How is the zoom level set for map view?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit

How does one set the zoom level on a mapview?

I have a map and when showing some locations, the name isnt displayed as the map isnt zoomed in enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explicitly set the zoom level for [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html), instead you set a visible [region](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setRegion:animated:) with a *MKCoordinateRegion* that includes a center point and the span of coordinates to display.